# How to Use Default Auto-Generated Menu?

Tags: menus, navigation

I have a site with a decent number of pages (130+) and it is organized using the Parent functionality of each post. This works well.

I'm trying to use a mega menu plugin, but it wants me to select a menu, but it doesn't show this automatic menu.

Is there a way to have a custom menu generated from and synced with this auto-menu?

Comment: fyi, that menu is generated by [`wp_page_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu), which is the default fallback function if a menu doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. I found that there are plugins that will let me sync this into a custom menu - e.g. Nested Pages - so that seems to be working.